# Normal Setups in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, clickonce, executable

Just wondering if there's a way to make Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition generate **normal** exe files that are created by the installer for my app?

I am sick of the ClickOnce application files. I had all these file associations setup and now that I need to actually have an installer for my apps, the file associations setup in the code don't work because now they're "ClickOnce" app files and not normal exe files. And no, VS does **not** create any exe files at all for ClickOnce apps.

Any help is much appreciated

thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can VS Express create Setup.Exe? No.

If you examine the license you will find that the Express edition is not intended to make distributions (I don't have the exact wording here). So MS left the Setup generator out of the package.

You can use any 3rd party setup maker but then you might be violating the license.

---

Edit: the above applies to VS2005 Express.

The licenses for 2008 and 2010 Express seem to be more lenient, do check.

Answer (score 1):

```
ProjectFolder\bin\Debug
```

Should contain .exe files for your application.

If you want to use the EXEs for deployment, however, you should create a "Release build."

Once you do that, your files will be in

```
ProjectFolder\bin\Release
```

Comment: Yes, that can be used for 'XCOPY deployment'. But the OP mentuons file associations.

Comment: *Never* provide Debug executables for installation, you have to compile in Release mode and distribute the exe located in ProjectFolder\bin\Release (or something like that, the default setting depend from the language, and it can still be changed in the properties of the project).

Comment: Yeah, it should have been `ProjectFolder\bin\Release`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember the Express edition do not provide tools for deployment, but still there are many free installers that can do the trick; you may want to try NSIS or InnoSetup, for example.

Answer (score -3):

Right Click your Solution > Add > Project > Other Project Types > Setup and Deployment > Visual Studio Installer > Setup Project

Comment: No, in the Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate RC =)