# simplified setup feature in Visual C# 2010 express

Tags: c#, winforms, deployment, installation

i just try visual studio c# 2010 express edition. According to [the website](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Charts/VisualStudio-Express-2010-Feature-Chart.aspx), this express edition support simplified setup. Can someone explain to me how to use this feature in express edition ? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

"simplified Setup" means you can right click the Project and select Publish. It will create a setup.exe which you can use. Also you can right click the Project Properties and change a few settings for the Setup.exe file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have used this feature already during the setup of VS Express.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269469/normal-setups-in-visual-studio/2269483#2269483

Comment: Thank you so much for the link, Henk ... I just curious about the statement in that website. It said that Visual Studio 2010 Express supports simplified setup. This feature i think is the same as Visual Studio 2008 standard edition's feature last time. Anyway, thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to create setup and deployment projects, these aren't available in the Express edition of Visual Studio.

Comment: But i still wonder why they put in the feature list in express edition ... Tkg