# Simple installer for Visual C# Express 2008

Tags: c#, deployment, installation

I am looking for some general feedback here.  I have a very simple application that I created in VC# Express 2008, with no special dependencies.

Now, I am going to release it as open source, and am curious as to how I should deploy it.  Do I need to create an installer package with any dll's?  Should I just zip up the *.exe file with a README?

Also, how should I go about handling the requirement for the .NET framework that a C# program needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/). That will handle .Net framework dependency.

Updated: As an open source project you don't need to include setup application. It is extra (fancy staff).

Comment: So you would suggest simply zipping it up and distributing that way?

Comment: But if you like to distribute assemblies, is better to create a setup.

Answer (score 1):

The express versions only include the Publish option (Click Once). I would advice to read the EULA first, there are restrictions on distributing applications made with the Express versions.

Also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269469/normal-setups-in-visual-studio/2269483#2269483).

Comment: What restrictions are there? From the FAQ (http://www.microsoft.com/express/Support/Support-faq.aspx)
Can I use Express Editions for commercial use?
Yes, there are no licensing restrictions for applications built using Visual Studio Express Editions.